# how to get device information on Android app from IBM bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, mqtt

I have created an app using IOT boilerplate in IBM Bluemix and added a devices as described in http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-mqtt-bluemix-iot-node-red-app/.

I have following queries

1. Is there a way I can retrieve devices information (`Authentication Token`, `Organization ID`) from my Android app. As at present, after creating the devices I need to fill this information manually in my Android app which may not be feasible in real life scenario.
2. Is there a way I can create this device on IBM Bluemix from Android App.

Regards,
Sengar

Answer (score 0):

You can [register](https://developer.ibm.com/iotfoundation/recipes/api-documentation/#registerDevice) a new device via the [HTTP API](https://developer.ibm.com/iotfoundation/recipes/api-documentation/). With this your android app can register it's self and will be given the required tokens to log into the service.

Comment: Thanks hardillb for response. Do you know any example usage of these bluemix APIs. I am trying to use it as given in http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html , but every time gets an exception file not found. I am able to get the response if using the same URL through browser. I am new to application world so my apology if this question is very basic.

Comment: Got the bluemix client https://github.com/ibm-messaging/iot-java . I hope it will resolve the issue.